# How to annotate Laravel Collection elements during iteration

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, psalm-php

I was thinking about how to annotate types in PhpStorm. I believe PhpStorm is using Psalm to resolve types, but I can't find how to annotate type to get suggestions here:

[image]

`$row` in my app will always be `Collection` object and I want to have it marked somewhere here with annotations.

Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish that?

```php
    /**
     * @param Collection $rows
     */
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            dump($row->); // $row is also Collection object
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check [laravel ide helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper).

Comment: See https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2021/07/phpstorm-2021-2-release/#collections_with_template -- you would need to use the generic + `@template` stuff (plus, the Psalm plugin must be enabled (even if it does not run it, it just used to support the syntax))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can mark var type like this:

```
/**
 @var $row Collection
**/
dump($row->);
```

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000701884-Using-var-type-hinting-with-properties-instantiated-by-Traits

Comment: I don't think `$row` is supposed to be a `Collection`, `$rows` is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics:

```
    /**
     * @param Collection<Collection> $rows
     */
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            dump($row->); // $row is also Collection object
        }
    }
```

which are supported in most modern IDE such as PHPStorm.